# how to pass json data from view to controller through redirect function in codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, controller

I have a json data in view page. I decoded the json and got an array o/p.
 I want this array to get in the controller using redirect function.

```
I tried this:
$this->session->set_userdata('deliverdata', $array);
```

How i can get the data in controller?

Comment: can you post the array as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use session class ( [Codeigniter Session](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) ) method

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item','value');
```

and then read it with

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view file edit like following

```
$data = array(
'myData' =  $array
);
$this->session->set_userdata('deliverdata', $data);
```

And you can get the full data as array in your controller.

```
$data =  $this->session->userdata('myData');
```

You can check your array data by printing the array.

```
echo <pre>; print_r($data);
```